# Strange: delay caused by headers dwarfing other speed aspects! How to interpret these speed charts?

Tags: php, optimization, header, performance, thumbnails

on various speedtest websites, amongst which site-perf.com I see the `header` causing relatively the largest delay for the website to load. On other speedtest charts i see the same, namely: while connection, ques, resolve, body are all fine, the `header` seems to take oddly long time. A note to be mentioned is that the .jpg files are very tiny thumbnails that are generated by a php script. (look at the size of them: tiny!)

In various trials, for example the two printscreens below that were set two weeks apart, i have more or less the same result: huge yellow bars dwarfing delays caused by other aspects.

**Q1. Interpreting Chart:** Am i interpreting these pictures properly at all? Could the yellow be actually a "polluted" delay where its slow load is due to many factors combined (slow internet connection, slow recolve etc, and not so contrasty to be blaimed at the `headers` in the chart?

**Q2. Rule Out Odds:** if you try to test your own website with similar size/load at http://site-perf.com, do you get a similar chart as I get?

**Q3. Whats Causing Yellow:** looking at such results (pictures) what could be causing the relatively higher percentages seen, caused as what is described as `header`?

**Q4. Clues & Remedies:** what could I do/try, to reduce the percentage of time lost in yellow here?

Thanks very much +!

---

`PIC1`
[image]

---

`PIC2`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's counting everything that happens inside your page's `<head>` block as headers, so start commenting out things. If you're pre-loading a ton of images with javascript and that's loaded in a `<script>` tag within the header, then those images' load times will count towards header times. Especially since it looks like you're loading from at least 4 different domains (going by the .com, .es, .de, .ch), and the images coming from those external domains/sites seem to be going rather slowly.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  The javascript sits all the way at the bottom, just before closing </html> it loads 2 sprite PNG images. both very,very tiny!

Comment: What else are you loading up in the page's `<head>` block? Obviously something's taking up a lot of time.

Comment: Dear Marc B, so you are saying that the yellow bars (headers) are the same as whats inside <head> </head> ???  I thought those headers were stuff that goes all the way up, before page file loading for example Expire, Cache controll, Keep Alive etc... Im confused